# how to scrape a web-page with search bar results, when the search query does not appear in the url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape search results within a webpage but when i type int te search bar (i.e. ABC) it does not reflect the search in the URL so when I use BeautifulSoup4 to scrape the URL it give me 'None',

Is there a way to find/write the URL with the search parameter included?

I have tried using 'BeautifulSoup with 'requests' and the 'lxml' parser, but the results are aways 'None'.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('URL').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

article = Soup.find('div')
print(article.prettify())

headline = article.div.hs.text
```

Comment: what's the source url?

Answer (score 0):

Beautifulsoap does not provide all scraping things . So using other metods more efficient like Selenium.I'm gonna show some of examples of using it.
If you haven't install it,you can install it on :

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/
```

Usage :

```
from  selenium import webdriver
url = "URL"
driver_path = r'chromedriverpath'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get(url)
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div") 
#For more specific :
x1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='classname']") 

for all in x:
    print(all.text)
```

Comment: thanks fro the help but i am still struggling to get it done. just to clarify the problem... if you go for example to a banks branch finder i.e.   https://www.barclays.co.uk/branch-finder/   and search for an area code. that search does not appear in the URL. so when you run a web scrap there is no information to be found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `requests.Response` object to see what the url was.

```
>>> import requests
>>> _tquery = requests.sessions.Session()
>>> qresults =  _tquery.request(method="get", url="https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20scraping%20module")

<Response [200]>

>>> qresults.url
'https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20scraping%20module'
```

BeautifulSoup is only going to help you with parsing the `text` attribute of the Response object.